NFS free space indication missing on Linux Mint 22 Cinnamon
I am running Linux Mint 22 Cinnamon with my DS923+ NAS mounted after login by clicking on it, full details here, only slightly changed since then, but the options and mount process are still the same or similar: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/783889/126755
Current fstab line (still not mounting automatically after login, I must click on it):
192.168.0.77:/volume3/nas-shared    /mnt/nas    nfs4    vers=4.1,proto=tcp,_netdev,bg,nofail,user,auto,rw,async,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=NAS    0    0

My problem here is that NFS free space indication is missing on the NAS, I would like to see it. All hints will be appreciated.
Because it is not possible to fully describe what I need only with words, let me attach image:


Comments section:

How and what exactly it should indicate? Answer: Like on NVM above. Used/Free space should it indicate.

Is there anything indicating that it is supposed to appear there? Have you looked at the configuration options for the file explorer that you are using? There no progress bar shown there but it does appear in the pie graph. Answer: Well, I don't know if NFS shares indicate used/free space by the progress bar, but if it is possible I would like to see it, on non-NFS like NVM ext4 mounted there you can see it just above it.

What file browser are you using? Is it Nemo? Answer: Yes, Nemo is the default file manager in Cinnamon and I use it.



From what I've researched and tried myself, there is no option to have Nemo show a bar for available disk space with either NFS or SMB/CIFS. That I know of, the only filesystem under Network that will show the the bar is SSHFS and it has to be mounted under /media. In fact, there have been requests to the developers to include this for NFS and SMB/CIFS in a future release.
For now, you'll need to rely on the pie graph.
